# Budget bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I'm looking for a pair of bluetooth head phones to tide me over until I can afford a good pair. (I love the Jaybird Bluebuds X - but after two years they've [broken](https://carltonbale.com/jaybird-bluebuds-x-bluetooth-headphones-review/).).

What's the best Bluetooth headphones I can get for around $US50?

Style doesn't matter -in ear/over ear doesn't matter. What we're looking for is decent sound quality, not going to fall apart, and comfortable if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the [Photive BTH3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HTPHK5W) Headphones off Amazon.com They go for just under $50. They are bluetooth, over the ear, have a built in mic and have a battery life of 12 hours (as they claim). The headphones also come with a carrying case. Hope this helps.